# git decoration is missing in vscode explorer in macOS

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a project and notice the git decoration in vscode explorer is gone. It was there before and I didn't use vscode for a long time.
I tried to add **"git.decorations.enabled": true** to my settings.json file and checked my git setting that the decoration is enabled but still there are no badges when I modify/create files. I don't know what I'm missing. Could someone give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to:

- update VSCode to its latest version
- restart it after setting modification
- launch it with [`--disable-extensions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions) to test if another extension would be the culprit.
- Relaunch it with all extension and add [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens)

Comment: Hi VonC, I followed the steps you suggested and installed GitLens, but still can't see the decorations

Comment: @xxddd_69 Even with all extension disabled?

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure I did it correctly, I just add "--disable-extensions" : true in the setting.json

Comment: @xxddd_69 No that would be more a command line option: `code --disable-extension`, as described in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions